# Назначить новую роль пользователя, если он кликает на ссылку определенной страницы

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Можно ли назначить пользователю новую роль автоматически, если он перейдет по определенной ссылке?
Например, сценарий такой: залогиненый пользователь бегает по сайту и видит ссылку "Получить более важную роль", жмет на неё и автоматически в админке меняется роль пользователя. Нужно, что бы ссылок было не ограниченное количество, так как ролей будет много. Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли назначить пользователю новую роль автоматически, если он
> перейдет по определенной ссылке?

Конечно можно. Для назначения новой роли можно использовать метод [WP_User::add_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_role/) или хук [add_user_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_user_role/).
Только стоит учесть, что идея с переприсвоеним роли по ссылке не очень хороша, тк такой способ потенциально небезопасен. Потому при конкретной реализации нужно предпринять дополнительные меры для обеспечения безопасности.

Comment: А какие меры безопасности, например?

Comment: Как минимум чтобы никто посторонний не смог переопределить себе права,  воспользовавшись ссылкой.

Comment: А не подскажете пример кода? ) А то я что то даже не понимаю как начать...

Comment: По ссылкам же есть примеры. А что именно и как делать - зависит от конкретных условий и задачи.

Comment: Конкретную задачу я ведь описала в вопросе. А по ссылкам я ничего похожего не вижу. Как например будет генерироваться ссылка на странице?